# How to change many .sra documents into one fastq document?

Tags: linux, fastq

I download a series of .sra which belong to one sample from NCBI. I tried to change one sra into fastq, but it is error.

My code: 
    `$fastq-dump I --split-files ERRXXXXX.sra.`

And My .sra document is paired.

I used `$fastq-dump SRR5XXXXX.sra` to change another process, and it worked well.

Therefore I would like to know how to make many .sra into one .fastq document? Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the whole message, but regarding your specific question "how to make many .sra into one .fastq document", the answer is pretty simple:

- Generate multiple fastq files from all the sra files you are interested in in the usual way.
- Concatenate all those fastq files in a single one: cat fastq1.fq fastq2.fq ... fastqN.fq > new_fastq.fq
- Remove intermediate files if no longer needed

The new_fastq.fq file contains all the information from the original sra files.

Take care and don't mix first and second ends in the same fastq (unless you know what you are doing, of course).